# node.js extends foo is not a function

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, sequelize.js, extends

I am using node.js with es6 beside sequelizejs.

My base class (base.js):

```
class base {

    constructor(table) {
        this._table = table;
    }

    all(query) {
        this._table.findAll({
        }).then(function (dbStatus) {
            return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                resolve(dbStatus);
            })
        });
    };
}
```

My derived class (city.js):

```
var util = require('util');
var base = new require('../base');


class city extends base {
   constructor() {
    super(db.city);
  }
}

module.exports = city;
```

Usage of derived class (cityrest.js) :

```
var city = new require('../../dataBaseOperations/city')
var app = express();

app.get('/all', function (req, res, next) {
    city.all(req.query, function (result, resultData) {
        if (result) {
            res.json({
                data: {
                    success: result,
                    content: resultData,
                    message: 'messageContent'
                }
            });
        } 

    })
})
```

Error is : **TypeError: city.all is not a function at cityrest.js**

Comment: Is this `var base = new require('../base');` really work? How you exposing **Base** - there is no exports or module.exports in the code. You probably want to execute `var base = new (require('../base'))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Require returns an object.
Try this:

```
var City = require('../../dataBaseOperations/city')
var city = new City()
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var base = new require('../base');
```

This line is basically equivalent to

```
var Base = require('../base');
var base = new Base(undefined);
```

Which means,

```
class city extends base {
```

extends not the class `Base`, but an instance of it. Skip the `new` keyword:

```
var Base = require('../base');

class City extends Base {
```

---

Similar issue here:

```
var city = new require('../../dataBaseOperations/city')
```

Omitting the brackets `()` at a class instance construction results in all constructor parameters set to `undefined`. This seems not be an issue in this case, however does not help the readability of your code. Instead, consider splitting the `require` and the instantiation:

```
var City = require('../../dataBaseOperations/city');
var city = new City();
```

---

As a side note, it is a common convention to name classes starting with a capital letter, while variables (e.g. holding class instances) should be named starting with a lower case letter.